# Unable to remove intel small business advantage

Tags: passwords, uninstall

When I try to remove intel small business advantage from my computer, it asks for a password. 
My windows password and Live account password is invalid, so what is that password?
This is new Windows 8 PC, and this came preinstalled.

Comment: Since this is a new system, contact the vendor for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Password is plain empty (i.e., just enter nothing and hit return) unless otherwise specified. Cheers!